# c++ segmentation fault in libcrafter

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, libcrafter

I am using the library Crafter in my c++ program. When calling the function

```
 Crafter::GetMAC("192.168.1.10", "eth0");
```

I receive a Segmentation Fault, I looked into this method, which calls some other methods. The call stack is as follows:

```
  - Crafter::GetMAC("192.168.1.10", "eth0");
  - GetMACIPv4(net_addr, iterator->iface_name);
  - Packet::SendRecv(const string& iface, double timeout, int retry, const string& user_filter);
```

In the `SendRecv` I receive the Segmentation Fault at this line:

```
    if ((r = pcap_next_ex (handle, &header, &packet)) <= 0)
```

I run the program with valgrind and the stacktrace output of the error I receive is the following:

```
    ==32555== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==32555==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
    ==32555==    at 0x4E68DD0: Crafter::Packet::PacketFromIP(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) (PacketDecoder.cpp:599)
    ==32555==    by 0x406EA2: captureThreadCallback(unsigned char*, pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*) (NetworkStructure.cpp:17)
    ==32555==    by 0x50CE805: pcap_handle_packet_mmap (pcap-linux.c:4546)
    ==32555==    by 0x50D31D0: pcap_read_linux_mmap_v3 (pcap-linux.c:4825)
    ==32555==    by 0x50D76AC: pcap_loop (pcap.c:868)
    ==32555==    by 0x406F65: captureThread(void*) (NetworkStructure.cpp:35)
    ==32555==    by 0x53120A4: start_thread (pthread_create.c:309)
    ==32555==    by 0x5B47CFC: clone (clone.S:111)
```

The installed version of `libcrafter` is 0.2, and from `libpcap` 1.6.2-1

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Due to using a null pointer. iterator should be given a value before being used.

Comment: The iterator is not null, I have tried it also with hardcoded values. Updated the post, sorry for the confusion, but still get the same result

Comment: PacketFromIP just calls Decode, Decode deletes the layers. It could be there, if a layer on the stack is a null ptr?